# How to pass a Twig Variable into a JS File

Tags: javascript, twig

I have a Twig variable `{{ myVar }}` and I need to pass it into Javascript. I'm wondering, how would I do that?

I've looked at a few similar solutions, but they all require that the Javascript is written inside the Twig file instead of inside an actual .js.

Comment: That's actually not a problem specific to Twig; what about writing it to an HTML5 `data` attribute, or even an `input type="hidden"`?

Comment: @gustavohenke I didn't think of taking advantage of the `data` attribute. Thank you. Can you respond as a reply so I can mark it as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already seem to know, writing JS code in the HTML is not a good practice. If you mix templating variables, it will be even harder to you when it comes the time to refactor your HTML/JS.
So, basically, that's not a problem specific to Twig.

Two ways of solving this problem that we use in my company are:

1. Take advantage of the `data` attributes of HTML5
   They're a great way to store some info, and jQuery can even retrieve them in the JS type you need!
2. Use `<input type="hidden" />` fields.