# Access data from res.render on clientSide using Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My serverside code in Node.JS (using Express) is as follows

```
res.render('index', {
    startDateTime: startDateTime,
    endDateTime: endDateTime
});
```

I'd like to access startDateTime and endDateTime on the clientside using Javascript. I know I can access them using Jade by doing `#{startDateTime}` . Is there a similar approach for Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question right, you're wanting to send those variables to an external `.js` file. If that's the problem, I've answered it [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332556/how-to-pass-a-twig-variable-into-a-js-file/17332776#17332776), but I'm quoting it here:

> [...] Two ways of solving this problem that we use in my company are:
>
> 1. Take advantage of the `data` attributes of HTML5.
>      They're a great way to store some info, and jQuery can even retrieve them in the JS
>      type you need!
> 2. Use `<input type="hidden" />` fields.

Comment: Thanks!. I ended up using the 2nd method.